# Need help comparing data from 2 different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, comparison

I have 2 database tables, innov8_data & innov8_data_fps.

innov8_data is my master table, innov8_data_fps is populated once a day new data from a import script.

What I need to do is identify differences in innov8_data from the new data imported to innov8_data_fps.

my data structure is id, sku, free_stock for both tables.

First 3 rows of innov8_data;

```
1,08-143800-00,0
2,DC83406,8
3,HBS106,0
```

Now if the first 3 rows of innov8_data_fps are as follows;

```
1,08-143800-00,0
2,DC83406,8
3,HBS106,8
```

I need to be able to identify the changes to the free_stock column for items with the same sku. The id column isn't consistent with the same product in each as the new import can have more or less sku's.

Comment: After testing the solution provided by @WebLearner the query needs a little more work.

The value of 8 or 0 in the 3rd column is a flag for in or out stock for the product.

I need the result to tell me which have changed from 0 to 8, and also 8 to 0 then I can process the changes to the products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to modify the code SQL statement posted earlier and now have it working as I wanted, thanks for your help.

```
SELECT t1.*,
t1.free_stock <> t.free_stock  `changes`
FROM innov8_data t
JOIN innov8_data_fps t1
  ON(t.sku = t1.sku)
WHERE t1.free_stock <> t.free_stock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so

```
SELECT t.*,
t1.free_stock - t.free_stock  `changes`
FROM innov8_data t
JOIN innov8_data_fps t1
  ON(t.sku = t1.sku)
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb514/4)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer basically nails it, except for not filtering out results where 'changes' = 0. If that's desired, I suggest this enhancement:

```
SELECT t.*,
t1.free_stock - t.free_stock  `changes`
FROM innov8_data t
JOIN innov8_data_fps t1
  ON(t.sku = t1.sku)
WHERE t1.freestock - t.free_stock != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked great. Only error I noticed was he first instance of freestock on the last line is missing an underscore.